# How to turn off MarkLogic Java API logging?

Tags: java, marklogic

I have trouble turning off MarkLogic log messages like these when uploading files to MarkLogic database through Java API:

```
16:24:01.599 [main] INFO  com.marklogic.client.io.DOMHandle - Serializing DOM document to output stream
```

I followed the information in MarkLogic Java API documentation about logging [MarkLogic Java API documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/logging). Here is how I initialize database client and xmlDocMgr:

```
databaseClient = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(marklogicHost, marklogicPort, marklogicUser, password, Authentication.DIGEST);

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
RequestLogger logger = databaseClient.newLogger(out);
logger.setEnabled(false);

xmlDocMgr = databaseClient.newXMLDocumentManager();
xmlDocMgr.stopLogging();
```

What am I doing wrong? How to disable log messages?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation section you referenced is unrelated--it's a different kind of logging you *could* use.

What you're seeing is that MarkLogic Java API uses [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping) for logging, and you should configure it with your perferred logging framework.  In the current release (3.0.6) we include logback which automatically enables the logging you're seeing.  We removed logback from future releases since it's not really required, and the SLF4J philosophy is to allow you to choose your preferred logging framework.

In any case, assuming you'd like to keep logback.  Add a file named "logback.xml" to your classpath with the level set to "WARN" as in the following suggested contents:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was able to configure logging of com.marklogic.client.io.DOMHandle through log4j.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the docs, I believe you need to call "xmlDocMgr.startLogging(logger)" first, which will register the RequestLogger with xmlDocMgr.

The "stopLogging" call doesn't do anything based on what's in the docs:

"If called on a manager not currently logging, nothing happens, not even an error or exception."

Comment: I tried that but no luck. I noticed in MarkLogic Java API posted on github that they are checking if logger is enabled.
`public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
  try {
   if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
    logger.info("Serializing DOM document to output stream");`

Logger is created like this:
`static final private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DOMHandle.class);`

Here is the link to whole class: https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/7e9cc12e59ec2ac730bbe8d5b1522c220f51349a/src/main/java/com/marklogic/client/io/DOMHandle.java

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the following section in POM to disable the log output.

```
<!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>-->
```